# Изменять value при нажатие checkbox

Tags: jquery

Вкратце..
Задумка такая:
Есть поле с числом, и несколько чекбоксов с процентом.
При первом нажатие на чекбокс, нужно прибавить процент к числу в поле, при втором нажатии вернуть исходное значение (по факту отнять процент).

Написал вот такое вот, но оно косячит только в путь.

Помогите заставить это работать.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
  var PCTthis = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var price = parseFloat($('input[name="price"]').val());

  if($(this).prop('checked'))
    var pricePCT = ((price * PCTthis / 100) + price);
  else
    var pricePCT = ((price * PCTthis / 100) - price);
  $('input[name="price"]').val(pricePCT);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="price" value="100" readonly>
<br>
<input id="f1" type="checkbox" name="f1" value="10">
<label for="f1">10%</label>
<br>
<input id="f2" type="checkbox" name="f2" value="20">
<label for="f1">20%</label>
<br>
<input id="f2" type="checkbox" name="f2" value="30">
<label for="f1">30%</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
  var PCTthis = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var price = parseFloat($('input[name="price"]').val());

  if($(this).prop('checked'))
    var pricePCT = price * (1 + PCTthis / 100);
  else
    var pricePCT = price / (1 + PCTthis / 100);
  $('input[name="price"]').val(pricePCT.toFixed(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="price" value="100" readonly>
<br>
<input id="f1" type="checkbox" name="f1" value="10">
<label for="f1">10%</label>
<br>
<input id="f2" type="checkbox" name="f2" value="20">
<label for="f1">20%</label>
<br>
<input id="f2" type="checkbox" name="f2" value="30">
<label for="f1">30%</label>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы снова меня выручили :)